# How to find maximum and minimum volumes of solid obtained by rotating $y=\sin x$ around $y=c$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, volume

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: Let $S$ be the region bounded by the curves $y=\sin x \ (0 \leq x \leq \pi)$ and $y=0$.
Let $V(c)$ be the volume of the solid of obtained by rotating the region $S$ around the line $y=c \ (0 \leq c \leq 1)$.

1. Find $c_1$ such that $V(c_1)$ is the minimum of $V(c)$.
2. Find $c_2$ such that $V(c_2)$ is the maximum of $V(c)$.

Comment: Is there any final solutions? Do you have any? Have you tried working to find the right integral?

Comment: @user: When the shape $S$ is rotated around the axis $y=c$ for a $c\in\ ]0,1[\ $ part of the generated volume $V$ is covered twice. Shall it be counted once or twice?

Comment: @Christian Blatter My interpretation is that we work with volume, not weighted volume. That is, overlap counts once.

Comment: Evaluate
$$ 2 \pi \int \int x  dx\,dy= \pi \int _0^c  (\sin^{-1}y)^2 \, dy $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. If $\frac{1}{2}\le c\le 1$, then
$$ V(c)=2c^2\pi^2-2\int_0^{\arcsin c}\pi(\sin x-c)^2dx. $$
If $0<c<\frac{1}{2}$, then
$$ V(c)=\int_{\arcsin c}^{\pi-\arcsin c}\pi(\sin x-c)^2dx+2c^2\pi\arcsin (2c)-2\int_{\arcsin c}^{\arcsin(2c)}\pi(c-\sin x)^2dx-2\int_0^{\arcsin c}\pi(c-\sin x)^2dx. $$
I will come back to finish this.

Comment: Will you really? :)

Comment: @user89499 Even though this question is in the unanswered queue, I think it is a somewhat not very well-versed problem (not like that revolution maximum volume, find $y(a/2)$ problem you offered bounty last month or so). Will the revolution overlapping just be hollow?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I think it's widely accepted that rotating a disk about its diameter should produce a closed ball, not an empty set.

Answer (score 5):

We will use the disk (or annulus) method to compute the volume of revolution.

---

For $c\in\left[0,\frac12\right]$, the points of intersection are $x=\sin^{-1}(c)$ and $x=\sin^{-1}(2c)$

$\hspace{1cm}$[image: points of intersection]

So, by symmetry, the volume is
$$
\begin{align}
&2\pi\left(\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(c)}\left(c^2-(c-\sin(x))^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_{\sin^{-1}(c)}^{\sin^{-1}(2c)}c^2\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_{\sin^{-1}(2c)}^{\pi/2}(\sin(x)-c)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\[6pt]
&=\pi^2c^2+4\pi c-3\pi c\sqrt{1-c^2}-\pi(2c^2+1)\sin^{-1}(c)
-2\pi c\sqrt{1-4c^2}+\pi\cos^{-1}(2c)
\end{align}
$$
whose derivative is
$$
4\pi\left(1-\sqrt{1-c^2}+c\cos^{-1}(c)-\sqrt{1-4c^2}\right)
$$
which is increasing on $\left[0,\frac12\right]$ and $0$ when $c\doteq0.4133664985118219064957589$.

---

For $c\in\left[\frac12,1\right]$, the intersection at $\sin^{-1}(2c)$ goes away

$\hspace{1cm}$[image: point of intersection]

So, by symmetry, the volume is
$$
\begin{align}
&2\pi\left(\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(c)}\left(c^2-(c-\sin(x))^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_{\sin^{-1}(c)}^{\pi/2}c^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)\\[6pt]
&=\pi^2c^2+4\pi c-3\pi c\sqrt{1-c^2}-\pi(2c^2+1)\sin^{-1}(c)
\end{align}
$$
whose derivative is
$$
4\pi\left(1-\sqrt{1-c^2}+c\cos^{-1}(c)\right)
$$
which is positive for $c\in\left[\frac12,1\right]$.

---

Plotting volume vs $c$:

$\hspace{1cm}$[image: result plot]

We get the extremes to be
$$
\begin{array}{}
&c&\text{volume}\\
&0.0000000000000000&4.9348022005446793\\
c_1=&0.4133664985118219&1.9531551992492437\\
c_2=&1.0000000000000000&7.6315684138144936
\end{array}
$$

Comment: It's nice to see that we got the same derivatives (as well as the same answer); but using $\cos^{-1}$ as you did gives a simpler-looking derivative.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbf{A)}$ If $\frac{1}{2}\le c\le1$, we have that
$$V(c)=\int_0^{c}2\pi(c-y)(\pi-2\sin^{-1}y)dy=$$

$$2\pi\bigg[-\frac{\pi}{2}(c-y)^2-2cy\sin^{-1}y-2c\sqrt{1-y^2}+y^2\sin^{-1}y-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}y+\frac{1}{2}y\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg]_{0}^{c},$$

so$\;\;\;$ $V(c)=2\pi\big(-c^2\sin^{-1}c-\frac{3}{2}c\sqrt{1-c^2}+\frac{\pi}{2}c^2+2c-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}c\big)$

and $\;$ $V^{\prime}(c)=2\pi\big(\pi c+2-2c\sin^{-1}c-2\sqrt{1-c^2}\big)$.

Since $V^{\prime}(\frac{1}{2})=2\pi(2-\sqrt{3}+\frac{\pi}{3})>0$ and $V^{\prime\prime}(c)=2\pi(\pi-2\sin^{-1}c)>0$ for $c\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$,

$\;\;\;$V is increasing on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

$\mathbf{B)}$ If $0\le c\le\frac{1}{2}$, we have that

$\displaystyle V(c)=\int_0^{c}2\pi(c-y)(\pi-2\sin^{-1}y)dy+\int_{2c}^{1}2\pi(y-c)(\pi-2\sin^{-1}y)dy=$

$\;\;\;\;\;$ $2\pi\bigg[-\frac{\pi}{2}(c-y)^2-2cy\sin^{-1}y-2c\sqrt{1-y^2}+y^2\sin^{-1}y-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}y+\frac{1}{2}y\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg]_{0}^{c}-2\pi\bigg[-\frac{\pi}{2}(y-c)^2-2cy\sin^{-1}y-2c\sqrt{1-y^2}+y^2\sin^{-1}y-
\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}y+\frac{1}{2}y\sqrt{1-y^2}\bigg]_{2c}^{1}$

$\;\;\;\;$$=2\pi\big(-c^2\sin^{-1}c-\frac{3}{2}c\sqrt{1-c^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}c+2c+\frac{\pi}{2}(1-c)^2+\pi c$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ $-\frac{\pi}{4}-c\sqrt{1-4c^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}2c\big)$.

Then $V^{\prime}(c)=2\pi\big(\pi c+2-2c\sin^{-1}c-2\sqrt{1-c^2}-2\sqrt{1-4c^2}\big)$

so
$V^{\prime}(0)=-4\pi$ and $V^{\prime\prime}(c)=2\pi\big(\pi+\frac{8c}{\sqrt{1-4c^2}}-2\sin^{-1}c\big)>0$  for $0<c<\frac{1}{2}$ since $\pi>2\sin^{-1}c$.

Since $V^{\prime}(\frac{1}{2})=2\pi\big(2-\sqrt{3}+\frac{\pi}{3}\big)>0$,$\;\;$ $V(c)$ has exactly one local minimum on $(0,\frac{1}{2})$

at the solution of the equation

$V^{\prime}(c)=2\pi\big(\pi c+2-2c\sin^{-1}c-2\sqrt{1-c^2}-2\sqrt{1-4c^2}\big)=0$,

which is approximately given by $c\approx.4133665$.

$\mathbf{C)}$ Since $$V(1)=\frac{8\pi-\pi^{2}}{2}>\frac{\pi^2}{2}=V(0),$$

$\:\:$ we can conclude that $V(c)$ has a minimum for $c\approx.4133665$
and a maximum for $c=1$.

.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .

Notice that the integrand in both integrals could have been simplified using the equation $\pi-2\sin^{-1}y=2\cos^{-1}y$.

Comment: I see you've used cylindrical shells and I've used disks (annuli really). It's nice we get the same answer :-) (+1)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer; I was planning to add the setup for the disc method to my answer just for completeness, but now I don't need to.  (The integration is actually a little simpler with your method than with mine.)

Comment: Notice that we also could have found $V^{\prime}(c)$ without actually calculating $V(c)$ by using the Chain Rule and part I of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.